# Quorum privateFor visibility

Tags: transactions, private-blockchain, quorum, privacy

Our current project requires that the recipients of a private transaction are unknown to the rest of the network.

So my question is: is the *privateFor* field dropped before sending the transaction to the Ethereum-Network?

To me this would make sense since this field isn't needed after the Transaction is sent over the Constellation-Network.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

privateFor field is not written into the txn data and thus is not sent on to any other participating nodes. The actual txn with privateFor field is processed by quorum node and is sent to the underlying constellation node. Constellation communicates with recipients to transfer the actual payload and returns txn hash: this is whats actually written onto txn in the blocks. This is illustrated here:

[image]